# yii2 global behavior to check language in module

Tags: yii2, yii-rest

I have api module in Yii2 app. Before any reuqest I need to check did user send language in post or get request. If user did not send language then throw exception with 422 code.

I have module Api.php. I should configure only for this module.

Comment: Hi can you give more info?

Comment: I have api module. In every request user should give param "lang" in GET or POST request. If there is not any I should throw exception

Comment: what kind of controller you have? REST or WEB?

Comment: You have REST controllers ? In api module

Comment: yes I use rest controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create behavior BeforeActionValidator, then create method beforeAction inside create validation rule with HttpException. Here is example:

```
class BeforeActionValidator extends Behavior
{

    public $rules = [];

    public function events()
    {
        return [
            Controller::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION => 'beforeAction'
        ];
    }


    public function beforeAction()
    {
        $lang = Yii::$app->request->get('lang', null)??Yii::$app->request->post('lang', null);
        if ($lang == null) {
            throw new HttpException(422,"lang is required");
        }
    }
}
```

And then attach this behavior to config file. In your module.

```
public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        \Yii::configure($this,
            [
                'as globalAccess' => [
                    'class' => BeforeActionValidator::class,
                ]
            ]);
    }
```

If you want you can add other events. Like AFTER_REQUEST

Comment: Init() method is where?

Comment: in the module you want